# Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters' in angular 6

Tags: angular

I'm using Full Calendar Plugin in this app.

Getting the below error when I run ng serve.

I'm using angular 6 and my typescrit version is 2.9.2

I even tried updating the typescript version and error is gone. But when I recompile it it is throwing error like angular 6 requires typescript >=2.7.2 and <2.10.

```
ERROR in node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(136,64): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(584,10): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(588,75): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(588,119): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(2457,74): error TS1122: A tuple type element list cannot be empty.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(2458,51): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(2460,9): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(2463,9): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
```

Comment: What version of FullCalendar are you using ? You should have a `@types/fullcalendar` dependency in your `package.json` also. It might be because this package was not updated after you upgraded the FullCalendar dependency ?

Comment: @AlexBeugnet "@fullcalendar/angular": "^4.3.1", "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.3.0". And @types/fullcalendar:"^4.3.1" included in DevDependencies still same error.

Comment: this may not be the answer you want, but I spent a day trying to work this out. Full Calendar docs and the angular connector clearly state they support Angular 7. At the end of the day, to get this working on my app I found this great article which I used and it worked https://medium.com/aubergine-solutions/how-to-integrate-jquery-fullcalendar-in-angular-c35728cfeeb2. Granted it may not be the solution, you are looking for. Please note that if you already had some jQuery functions, adding the jQuery types, may highlight them as undefined, in which case you may just need to add the various type